# Excel QFD (Quality Function Deployment)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I am trying to make a QFD on excel.
The horizontal rows are easy to do but I do not know how to make the diagonal intersecting rows.
An example QFD is http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/A1_House_of_Quality.png
I have found one way to do it, on yahoo answers, but it seems very inefficient.
http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100101121050AADCaqW

How do I make the intersecting diagonal columns for a QFD in excel?

Thanks

Comment: Excel is first & foremost a spreadsheet application, not an infographic application. I'm not aware of any built-in functionality that would replicate this look and feel, at least not without a good amount of manual intervetion (like the Yahoo! answer) or some visual basic.  That said, perhaps someone else knows a good way to do this. Good luck!

Comment: David, looks like you're right, I'm going to have to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly created using diagonal borders.

- Increase the `Zoom` of the worksheet
- Using the **Draw Borders** button it is possible to repeatedly draw diagonals - but it takes precision, this is why you need to zoom
- Merged cells may also be used
- Once you've got a selection of different borders and merged cells, click in one of these and double-click the `Format Painter` so that you can repeatedly apply its formatting to other cells
- When you insert a Shape, and as you drag it, hold the `Alt` key so that it will fit neatly in the cell
- If you are inserting an Oval hold the `Shift` key as you drag it so that it will be a perfect circle, the same for other shapes. (You can hold both Alt and Shift at the same time, but it's probably not necessary)
- Double or right-click a shape to locate the Format options. Here you can specifically set `Rotation` as 45 degrees
- With care, you can copy and paste these shapes to different cells.

**Hint**: For the main columns, that look like single columns, they should be two columns - with a lot of merging. Again, the `Format Painter` can help with this.

**Hint2** Make the rows and columns for the top area the same width and height before you begin.

**Hint3** Holding `Alt` as you drag row or column height/width will display the width in pixels.

Comment: .. or don't use Excel for this :)

Comment: Sorry, one last hint - get some graph paper and plan it on there first. (I must get a life :) )

Comment: Thanks Andy, appreciate it